# Use lag function in R to call multiple values

Tags: r, rows, lag

I made a similar question : [If condition is met, go 6 rows above and select the value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568689/if-condition-is-met-go-6-rows-above-and-select-the-value-in-r/65568979#65568979) and I received a very usefyl answer.

Now I am trying to call instead of 1 value as in the previous topic, multiple rows instead.

Sample data:

```
    md2 <- structure(list(Hdwy = c(45.01, 45.03, 449, 44.46, 43.63, 425, 
41.36, 40.53, 40.1, 39.97, 39.98, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41.36, 40.53, 
40.1, 40, 40), L_ID = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

I used :

```
library(dplyr)
spc <- md2 %>%
         mutate(Lag = lag(Hdwy, (1:6)) %>%
         filter(L_ID==1) %>%
         pull(Lag)
spc
```

Expecting to see:

```
> spc 44.46, 43.63, 425, 
>     41.36, 40.53, 40.1
```

But I get the error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Lag`. x `n` must be a
> nonnegative integer scalar, not an integer vector of length 200. i
> Input `Lag` is `lag(Hdwy, (1:6))

Any ideas? Should I use a different function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lag` can accept only 1 number, you can try a rolling operation instead.

```
library(dplyr)

md2 %>% 
  mutate(Lag = lead(zoo::rollapply(L_ID == 1, 6, any, fill = NA, align = 'left'))) %>%
  filter(Lag) %>%
  pull(Hdwy)

#[1]  44.46  43.63 425.00  41.36  40.53  40.10  40.00
```

I do get another value 40 corresponding to the last 1.

If you want to get all the 6 values from the each 1 you can try this base R option.

```
inds <- which(md2$L_ID == 1)
md2$Hdwy[unique(sort(c(sapply(inds, `-`, 1:6))))]
```

Comment: Many thanks! I tried the rolling operation and works. I f I wanted to go 6 rows after the value instead would it work if I wrote : md2 %>% 
  mutate(Lag = lead(zoo::rollapply(L_ID == 1, - 6, any, fill = NA, align = 'left'))) %>%
  filter(Lag) %>%
  pull(Hdwy) ??

Comment: To get after values you can use `mutate(Lag = lag(zoo::rollapply(L_ID == 1, 6, any, fill = NA, align = 'right')))` keep remaining part same.